# Сайт работает с кодировкой utf-8, а БД строго стоит windows-1251

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8, charset

Сайт работает по кодировке urf-8, а вот БД по кодировке windows-1251. Проблема заключается в занесении информации в бд. Т.е русские символы хранятся в иероглифах. Если хостинг не предоставляет возможность сменить кодировку БД на utf-8 - менять хостинг? Я использую PDO и ставлю кодировку utf-8

Comment: можешь установить кодировку соединения: `SET NAMES 'utf-8'` или `SET CARACTER SET 'utf-8'`

Comment: http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: @Fat-Zer я использую PDO и указываю utf-8

Comment: Заголовок вопроса стоит сменить. Вопрос не об отличии кодировок, а об корректном сохранении данных с кодировкой UTF-8 в базе MySQL

Comment: @Лукас, хз... должно работать поидей... хотя я не особо много имел дел с php... может у тебя в базу данные изначально были занесены в неверной кодировке? ну и как уже заметили выше «utf-8 во все поля!»...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Напишите в тех.поддержку, только они знают что творится на их серверах и как управлять этими настройками. Если ответы будут "мутными", смело переходите на новый хостинг и не жалейте об этом ни секунды, так как проблему выявили до запуска проекта, а не после напоровшись на грабли.

**2)** Приведите в пример код, которые заносит в БД информацию, хотя по на примере 1 поля, но чтобы код внесения был полностью описан.

**3)** Что происходит когда вы пытаетесь сменить кодировку бД? Или ее у вас вообще нельзя менять?

**4)** Стоят ли у вас соотношения полей внутри таблицы UTF8? Те поля, в которых буквы заносятся как иероглифы.

Comment: 1) Я писал, мне ответили что у них строго по умолчанию стоит windows-1251 и нет возможности сменить на utf-8.
2) $query = "INSERT INTO `users_tarifs`(`user_id`, `tarif_id`, `sum`, `date`, `date_next_reple`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
              $res = $db::sendSql($query, array($user_id, $tarif->id, $tarif->sum, $nowSqlFormat, $nextData)); 
Использую свою обвертку PDO внутри выполняется функция prepare, execute
3) Ее нельзя сменить
4) Да

Comment: @Лукас  Давайте сделаем очень простой ход для решения задачи. У вас наверняка есть свободный хостинг с кодировкой utt-8, перекиньте туда проект и скажите, решился ли вопрос, если нет, занчит дело не в кодировках вовсе, если да, меняйте хостинг. Если у вас нет свободного хоста, воспользуйтесь бесплатными, коих десяток как минимум можно найти для теста.

Comment: Перенес на другой веб-хостинг, проблема решилась.